# AttributeError at /user/ 'CommentSection' object has no attribute 'post' django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

When i try uploading a comment to a post i get this error
The post model is a foriegnKeyfield of the post the comment is posted on
I tried changing the model name but it did nothing i get the same error again
Here is the models code :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Meme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    op = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    comment = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms :

```
class CommentSection(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentSection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['comment'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

and here is the view :

```
def user_home(request):
    comment = CommentSection()
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = CommentSection(request.POST)
        if comment.is_valid():
            comment.save(commit=False)
            comment.op = request.user
            comment.not_post_method_ok.id = id
            comment.save()
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    imgs = Meme.objects.all()
    ctx = {
        'imgs': imgs,
        'comment': comment,
        'comments': comments,
    }
    return render(request, 'User_Home.html', ctx)
```

Full error :

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/?get_the_id=1

Django Version: 3.2.9
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'materializecssform',
 'cloudinary_storage',
 'cloudinary',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'Register_Page',
 'Post']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JEGAN\PycharmProjects\Memoster\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\JEGAN\PycharmProjects\Memoster\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JEGAN\PycharmProjects\Memoster\Post\views.py", line 39, in user_home
    comment.post.id = '1'

Exception Type: AttributeError at /user/
Exception Value: 'CommentSection' object has no attribute 'post'
```

the id i get works but for some reason i keep getting this error please help
and thanks a lot

Comment: Post the *full* traceback together with the `CommentSection` form.

Comment: OK give me a min

Comment: It seems that your view contains a line `comment.post.id = '1'` based on the traceback, but that line is *not* in the view you shared?

Comment: It is id variable is 1

Comment: yes, but the view you post here has no line `comment.post.id = '1'` so there seems to be a "mismatch" between the view you post, and the view that contains the bug.